# Double dollar sign or Variables in Aggregation Expressions in yml

Tags: java, yaml, wildfly, el, properties-file

How to access the value of variables in properties file - that has a leading double dollar sign.
"$$."

I have this variable in properties file - which later gets read into yaml using Expression language.

```
$$remoting.port: 8221
```

The below is how i try to pass the property value into yaml file.

```
http:
    port: ${remoting.port}
```

This is failing with the below error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${remoting.port}"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.spi:api@2.6.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.config.Builder.convert(Builder.java:126)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.spi:api@2.6.0.Final//org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.config.Builder.getValue(Builder.java:73)
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the EL expressions in YAML were *not* evaluated. What did you do to expect EL expressions in your YAML to be evaluated?

Comment: I tried to evaluate as in like the normal epression.  ${remoting.port}  then also tried to escape the double leading dollar sign. It was more of a guess game but no luck so far... hance I've put the question to get an assist

Comment: YAML itself does not know anything about EL. EL does not magically work on any file you happen to load. You need to inject an EL implementation *somewhere* so that it handles the expressions in the YAML file. It is unlikely that Wildfly Swarm does expose an API for it, so you need to preprocess the YAML file before loading it with Wildfly swarm. I don't know Wildfly so I can't help you with the details.